# Browser detection in PHP causes white screen

Tags: php, echo

I tried many times but I cannot make it work. It showed nothing. So, please help me fix it !

```
 <?php

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera') || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari') !== FALSE) 
                echo '<script>$(document).click(function() {
                      window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
                      });
                       </script>';
else
                echo '<form action="http://google.com" method="get" name="redirect"></form>
                <script> document.forms['redirect'].submit() </script>';

?>
```

Comment: `PHP: The code doesn't work` Very useful title! I could almost tell what the question is about

Comment: what error did you get ?

Comment: You forgot a few `)`!

Comment: I get nothing @Begueradj

Comment: Give more details,doesnt work is about as useful as me saying you have errors.

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't know what error, so I think it is best title

Comment: Solution: you forgot: 3x `)` and you have to escape 2x `'` in the second echo statement

Comment: STRPOS( "foo", "bar" ||   that isn't going to work.  You need to close the parens before the next test with the ||

Comment: @Mihai, Hi, I get nothing. I viewed source and saw nothing

Comment: @ChrisCaviness, I edited but still nothing

Comment: Is there a hat for attracting the most down votes in the less time possible?

Comment: Everyone's a software developer now.

Comment: The short version is... PHP is throwing an error but you've got error reporting turned off. Check your log files for the error message or edit your php.ini file to enable error reporting. Once you know what the error is, it should be easy to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first comment here sorry if its not perfect.
I think its because you're trying to echo everything at once.

```
<?php 
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') !== FALSE || 
    strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== FALSE ||
    strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera') !== FALSE || 
    strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari') !== FALSE) 
    {
                $str = '<script>$(document).click(function() {';
                $str .= ' window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");';
                $str .= ' });';
                $str .= ' </script>';
                echo $str;
 } else {
                $str = '<form action="http://google.com" method="get" name="redirect"></form>';
                $str .= '<script> document.forms[\'redirect\'].submit() </script>';
                echo $str;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

check each condition independantly

Like:

```
<?php

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') !== FALSE || 
    strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== FALSE ||
    strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera') !== FALSE || 
    strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari') !== FALSE) 
                echo '<script>$(document).click(function() {
                      window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
                      });
                       </script>';
else
                echo '<form action="http://google.com" method="get" name="redirect"></form>
                <script> document.forms[\'redirect\'].submit() </script>';

?>
```

Comment: How so, @Rizier123? If you respond to say something is wrong, it is helpful to say how.

Comment: Yes, it is still error

Comment: It's in the echo after the else.  Single quotes appearing in the single quoted string at 'redirect'

Comment: @Chris, thanks. Ganesh, if you fix several things in code, it is useful to point each of them out - otherwise they will be missed, as here.

Comment: Shoudnt else be followed by {}

Comment: Only necessary if you have more than one line of code.  However as a general rule, I always code block just to be safe.

Comment: I use "redirect" and the problem was solved

Comment: now please add your final answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
if ((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') ||
     strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') ||
     strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera') ||
     strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari')) !== FALSE )

     echo '<script>$(document).click(function() {
              window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
           });
           </script>';
else
    echo '<form action="http://google.com" method="get" name="redirect"></form>
          <script> document.forms[\'redirect\'].submit() </script>';

?>
```

Comment: Would you edit the question to explain what things you have fixed?